# why specify TRUE as array's key to check if variable is set?

Tags: php

I'm exploring the following piece of code in Kohana's sources:

```
foreach ($expected as $field)
{
    // Use the submitted value or NULL if no data exists
    $data[$field] = Arr::get($this, $field);

    if (isset($rules[TRUE]))
    {
        if ( ! isset($rules[$field]))
        {
            // Initialize the rules for this field
            $rules[$field] = array();
        }

        // Append the rules
        $rules[$field] = array_merge($rules[$field], $rules[TRUE]);
    }
}
```

I'm interested in this part `isset($rules[TRUE])` - what is the purpose of this check? Why does they specify `TRUE` as array's key?

I've also just found the next usage of this construction:

```
// Remove the rules that apply to every field
unset($rules[TRUE]);
```

Comment: I don't know kohana, but php TRUE constant has value 1 (so it is $rules[1]) - maybe this will help. http://codepad.org/wNQZH1r1

Comment: Looks like that last comment sheds light on the situation. It appears that `$rules['fieldName']` contains rules that are applicable to a specific field, whereas `$rules[TRUE]` contains rules that are applicable to all fields. I assume there's logic somewhere that accounts for that universal one. I suppose it could just as well have been called anything else such as `$rules['all']` but the developers wanted to avoid collisions if there happened to be a field named "all".

Comment: @Wiseguy, you're probably right. As I see it if rules that apply to every field exist - `isset($rules[TRUE])` then they are merged with fields defined with every field. Why don't you duplicate your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: Good point about merging them. I completely overlooked that line. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that last comment sheds light on the situation. It appears that `$rules['fieldName']` contains rules that are applicable to a specific field (in this example, a field named "fieldName"), whereas `$rules[TRUE]` contains rules that are applicable to all fields. I suppose it could just as well have been called anything else such as `$rules['all']` but the developers wanted to avoid collisions if there happened to be a field named "all".

Then the following line adds the universal rules to the rules for a specific field:

```
// Append the rules
$rules[$field] = array_merge($rules[$field], $rules[TRUE]);
```